# Prevent user to enter duplicate value in a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

In Microsoft excel, I am trying to prevent a user from entering duplicate values in the first row. The formula I'm using to validate this doesn't seem to work. I've tried the following:

1. Formula : `=COUNTIF($A1:A1,A1)=1` This approach kept on giving error in Excel 2016 so I had to remove the `=` sign.
2. Once done, It didn't let me enter any value in first row
3. Formula : `COUNTIF(1:1,A1)=1`
   Did not work either.
4. I even tried to drag the formula to maximum length. That did not help either.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you have circular logic going on. when you enter something in A1, there is a 100% guarantee that it will be in the range $A$1:A1.  The very first entry of data in a blank row or column is guaranteed to be unique.  As a result you do not need to check for uniqueness on the very first entry.  What it sounds like you are trying to do is either check if you entry matches any OTHER value in the row.

Comment: there are a few approaches you can take to correct this.  Either compare your value to the rest of the row but not your cell, or you want to flag when there is GREATER THAN 1 occurrence in the row.  Having said that you may wind up with a circular reference problem since the cell you are checking is part of the formula itself and excel tends not to like that which would bring you back to the first suggestion

Comment: Am not sure if the second argument of Countif takes a range. All possible attempts did fail . I tried the workaround, but the error keeps popping up. No matter what I write . Made attempt with both empty and uniquely filled cells

Comment: Might want to try something like COUNTIF($A$1:A1,B1)=1 but use it in cell B1, then copy cell B1 to the right

Answer (score 2):

The following formula for your data validation should work:

```
    =COUNTIF(1:1,A1)<=1
```

Comment: Was just about to type this

Answer (score -1):

At first i believe you should use ";" instead of "," like this: 
=countif(A1:A4;A1)... 
Then you have to create a =countif somewhere in the sheet before using Data Verification. 
Watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_pc4YGdeY4

Comment: All the given code snippets to find duplicate in *column* does work fine. Am trying to find duplicate in ROW

Comment: @Philip Karlsson - use of `,` (comma) or `;` (semi-colon) depends on the language of your Excel installation.

Comment: I merely use excel in work, I'm no expert and I thought it worked both with column and row. But glad you worked it out, atleast I learnt something. Thanks :)